# Errors while fetching data

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to fetch the data from this link:

```
 Future<String> fetchQuestion() async {


  var response =
      await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=boolean"),headers:{"Accept":"application/json"} );
setState(() {
  var responseBody=json.decode(response.body);
  data=responseBody["results"];
});
print(data);

return "Sucess";
}
```

And i wrote this to set the initial state to call the function:

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  this.fetchQuestion();
 }
```

and this is the scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Quiz')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>
          [Container(
          height: 200.0,
          child:Text(data[i]["question"]),
          ),
      Container(
      child:RaisedButton(
       child: Text(b1):Text(' '),
        onPressed: (){
          checkT();
          next();

        }
      ),
      ),
      Container(
      child:RaisedButton(
       child:  Text(b2),
        onPressed:(){
          checkw() ;
          next();
        }
      ),
      ),
```

when I tried to I got this error:
The method '[]' was called on null, then it refreshes itself and the app runs i don't know why. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` will be `null` for a few milliseconds until the http request makes the round trip to the server, returns and runs the code in `setState`, which sets `data` to the decoded response. During this time, flutter is going to try to paint the screen and can't build `Text(data[i]...` because data hasn't been initialized yet.

The fix is to detect that `data` is null and build something different, until it gets set:

```
  body: (data == null) ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Column(
    ...
```

Presumably you set `i` somewhere to a valid index into the list of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Because `data` is `null` until the network call finishes. Once data is fetched (`fetchQuestion`), `setState`(inside fetchQuestion) refreshes the view with non-null data that we got from network.

You might need a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for your use-case.